# Codeigniter logging users out

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am creating a web application with the codeigniter framework, am working with version 2.0.3.
My makes ajax requests to update the page from time to time, and fetch notifications.
I've visited the codeigniter forums and asking questions about codeigniter sessions and ajax and found this snippet of code which i used, and saved in libraries and class "My_session.php"

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    /**
     * Update an existing session
     *
     * @access    public
     * @return    void
    */
    function sess_update() {
       // skip the session update if this is an AJAX call! This is a bug in CI; see:
       // https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/154
       // http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/102456/P15
       if ( !($this->CI->input->is_ajax_request()) ) {
           parent::sess_update();
       }
    }
}
```

But ever since i added this code i am unable to stay logged for more than five minutes without being logged out, or sometimes not being able to login in at all.
Does anyone  have a similar experience?

Comment: are the time settings on your server ok?

Comment: @LastRoseStudios The time settings are correct

Comment: are you using the database for your sessions?

Comment: @tgriesser yes am using sessions with a database

Comment: okay because i'm having the same problem with an ajax heavy app, using the ajax request override with no luck, and also trying to track down what the problem might be, I have some ideas but i am trying to confirm. Is your session cookie encrypted?

Comment: @tgriesser yeah my session cookie is encrypted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay logged in longer you have set sess_expiration for more then five minutes in your application/config/config.php

Comment: its set 7200 seconds that two hours

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you evaluate the is_ajax_request()? in that code snippet add:

```
echo 'AJAX: ' . $this->CI->input->is_ajax_request(); exit;
```

to see if the if statement is working correctly.  it might be returning false and updating the session each time.  just a quick place to start :)

Comment: check to see if AJAX is == to true somewhere in the framework, if not then you need to add those checks, which is in the thread of the lib you added or define it at the top of the lib as a defined const, like so: `define('AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');`

Comment: sorry i didnt get back to you in time, it display 1 when its an ajax request